# adb backup not working for certain app

Tags: adb, backup

I need to get all files of a certain app (com.valvesoftware.android.steam.community), but adb backup only gives me a 1KB AES encrypted file. upon decrypting it there is nothing inside the tar archive

I tried: `adb backup -f steam.ab  -noapk com.valvesoftware.android.steam.community`

Upon entering my backup password (not the encryption password!) the `steam.ab` package is made. My problem is that there is just about 1KB of AES encrypted information in it.

However, it seems I can back up other apps just fine.

What is the cause of this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Developers can decide to have their apps opt-out of backups (`ALLOW_BACKUP=FALSE`). If you try to backup such an app via `adb backup`, the resulting file will contain nothing but the backup header (usually a 41 byte file). Working around that limitation is only possible on rooted devices, e.g. using the XPosed module [Backup All Apps](http://repo.xposed.info/module/com.pyler.backupallapps).