# Why is adb backup creating a 1KB backup file when backup is permitted for the app?

Tags: adb, backup

I am using adb (latest one) from [Android SDK Platform Tools](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools). I also 
 installed the adb driver from [Intel USB Drivers for Android Devices](https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-usb-driver-for-android-devices). 
All installation done on two computer, one with Windows 8.1, another with Windows 10. The phone being tested for this backup experiment is [TP-Link Neffos X1 Lite](https://www.gsm-specs.com/specifications/tp-link-neffos-x1-lite/).

I am using the commands given by Izzy as described in [Is it possible to backup and restore an app with data via ADB?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/182381/is-it-possible-to-backup-and-restore-an-app-with-data-via-adb) to backup the game [Jetpack Joyride](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.halfbrick.jetpackjoyride&hl=en_US).

```
adb backup -f myapp.ab -apk com.myapp # backup on one device
```

But, I end up with a 1KB backup file (not 0 KB or 41 bytes that Izzy mentioned there).

I tested with different modes (charging, MIDI, MTP and PTP) with same result of 1KB backup file.

Here is the manifest of the app:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<manifest
    versionCode='50199503'
    versionName='1.14.2'
    installLocation='0'
    compileSdkVersion='28'
    compileSdkVersionCodename='9'
    package='com.halfbrick.jetpackjoyride'
    platformBuildVersionCode='28'
    platformBuildVersionName='9'>
  <uses-sdk
      minSdkVersion='16'
      targetSdkVersion='26'
      xlargeScreens='true'>
  </uses-sdk>
  <uses-feature
      glEsVersion='0x00020000'>
  </uses-feature>
  <uses-feature
      name='android.hardware.touchscreen'
      required='true'>
  </uses-feature>
  <uses-permission
      name='android.permission.INTERNET'>
  </uses-permission>
  <uses-permission
      name='android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE'>
  </uses-permission>
  <uses-permission
      name='android.permission.WAKE_LOCK'>
  </uses-permission>
  <uses-permission
      name='com.android.vending.BILLING'>
  </uses-permission>
  <uses-permission
      name='android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE'>
  </uses-permission>
  <uses-permission
      name='com.google.android.finsky.permission.BIND_GET_INSTALL_REFERRER_SERVICE'>
  </uses-permission>
  <uses-permission
      name='com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE'>
  </uses-permission>
  <application
      theme='@res/0x7F0D0165'
      label='@res/0x7F0A00DB'
      icon='@res/0x7F030001'
      name='com.halfbrick.mortar.MortarApplication'
      backupAgent='com.halfbrick.mortar.SharedPrefBackupAgent'
      hardwareAccelerated='true'
      supportsRtl='true'
      resizeableActivity='false'
      appComponentFactory='android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory'>
    <meta-data
        name='io.fabric.ApiKey'
        value='3c59abf6040024f2e259d458cc26f0e7f1e305b7'>
    </meta-data>
    <meta-data
        name='com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon'
        resource='@res/0x7F0200C8'>
    </meta-data>
    <meta-data
        name='com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id'
        value='@res/0x7F0A00F8'>
    </meta-data>
    <activity
        theme='@res/0x7F0D0172'
        name='com.halfbrick.mortar.MortarGameActivity'
        launchMode='2'
        screenOrientation='6'
        configChanges='0x40000FFF'
        windowSoftInputMode='0x00000003'>
      <intent-filter>
        <action
            name='android.intent.action.VIEW'>
        </action>
        <category
            name='android.intent.category.DEFAULT'>
        </category>
        <category
            name='android.intent.category.BROWSABLE'>
        </category>
        <data
            scheme='jetpack'>
        </data>
      </intent-filter>
      <intent-filter
          autoVerify='true'>
        <action
            name='android.intent.action.VIEW'>
        </action>
        <category
            name='android.intent.category.DEFAULT'>
        </category>
        <category
            name='android.intent.category.BROWSABLE'>
        </category>
        <data
            scheme='http'
            host='jetpackjoyride.page.link'>
        </data>
        <data
            scheme='https'
            host='jetpackjoyride.page.link'>
        </data>
      </intent-filter>
      <meta-data
          name='com.halfbrick.mortar.GCMSenderId'
          value='id=897786220322'>
      </meta-data>
      <intent-filter>
        <action
            name='android.intent.action.MAIN'>
        </action>
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <receiver
        name='com.appsflyer.MultipleInstallBroadcastReceiver'
        exported='true'>
      <intent-filter>
        <action
            name='com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER'>
        </action>
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <meta-data
        name='com.google.android.gms.version'
        value='@res/0x7F0F0008'>
    </meta-data>
    <receiver
        name='com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementReceiver'
        enabled='true'
        exported='false'>
    </receiver>
    <receiver
        name='com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementInstallReferrerReceiver'
        permission='android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES'
        enabled='true'
        exported='true'>
      <intent-filter>
        <action
            name='com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER'>
        </action>
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <service
        name='com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementService'
        enabled='true'
        exported='false'>
    </service>
    <service
        name='com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementJobService'
        permission='android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE'
        enabled='true'
        exported='false'>
    </service>
    <activity
        theme='@res/0x01030010'
        name='com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiActivity'
        exported='false'>
    </activity>
    <activity
        theme='@res/0x01030010'
        name='com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.SignInHubActivity'
        exported='false'
        excludeFromRecents='true'>
    </activity>
    <service
        name='com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.RevocationBoundService'
        permission='com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.permission.REVOCATION_NOTIFICATION'
        exported='true'>
    </service>
    <activity
        theme='@res/0x0103000F'
        name='com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity'
        exported='false'
        configChanges='0x00000FB0'>
    </activity>
    <provider
        name='android.support.v4.content.FileProvider'
        exported='false'
        authorities='com.halfbrick.jetpackjoyride.AndroidShareFileProvider'
        grantUriPermissions='true'>
      <meta-data
          name='android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS'
          resource='@res/0x7F080001'>
      </meta-data>
    </provider>
    <meta-data
        name='com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId'
        value='@res/0x7F0A00FC'>
    </meta-data>
    <meta-data
        name='com.facebook.sdk.AutoLogAppEventsEnabled'
        value='false'>
    </meta-data>
    <meta-data
        name='com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID'
        value='@res/0x7F0A0103'>
    </meta-data>
    <activity
        name='com.ironsource.sdk.controller.ControllerActivity'
        configChanges='0x00000480'
        hardwareAccelerated='true'>
    </activity>
    <activity
        theme='@res/0x0103000F'
        name='com.ironsource.sdk.controller.InterstitialActivity'
        configChanges='0x00000480'
        hardwareAccelerated='true'>
    </activity>
    <activity
        theme='@res/0x0103000F'
        name='com.ironsource.sdk.controller.OpenUrlActivity'
        configChanges='0x00000480'
        hardwareAccelerated='true'>
    </activity>
    <activity
        name='com.adcolony.sdk.AdColonyInterstitialActivity'
        configChanges='0x000004A0'
        hardwareAccelerated='true'>
    </activity>
    <activity
        name='com.adcolony.sdk.AdColonyAdViewActivity'
        configChanges='0x000004A0'
        hardwareAccelerated='true'>
    </activity>
    <activity
        name='com.applovin.adview.AppLovinInterstitialActivity'>
    </activity>
    <activity
        name='com.applovin.adview.AppLovinConfirmationActivity'>
    </activity>
    <activity
        theme='@res/0x01030011'
        name='com.chartboost.sdk.CBImpressionActivity'
        excludeFromRecents='true'
        configChanges='0x000004A0'
        hardwareAccelerated='true'>
    </activity>
    <activity
        theme='@res/0x01030007'
        name='com.unity3d.services.ads.adunit.AdUnitActivity'
        configChanges='0x40000FFF'
        hardwareAccelerated='true'>
    </activity>
    <activity
        theme='@res/0x01030011'
        name='com.unity3d.services.ads.adunit.AdUnitTransparentActivity'
        configChanges='0x40000FFF'
        hardwareAccelerated='true'>
    </activity>
    <activity
        theme='@res/0x01030011'
        name='com.unity3d.services.ads.adunit.AdUnitTransparentSoftwareActivity'
        configChanges='0x40000FFF'
        hardwareAccelerated='false'>
    </activity>
    <activity
        theme='@res/0x01030007'
        name='com.unity3d.services.ads.adunit.AdUnitSoftwareActivity'
        configChanges='0x40000FFF'
        hardwareAccelerated='false'>
    </activity>
    <activity
        name='com.facebook.ads.AudienceNetworkActivity'
        configChanges='0x000004A0'
        hardwareAccelerated='true'>
    </activity>
    <activity
        theme='@res/0x01030007'
        label='HyprMX SDK'
        name='com.hyprmx.android.sdk.activity.HyprMXOfferViewerActivity'
        launchMode='1'
        configChanges='0x00000DA0'
        hardwareAccelerated='true'>
    </activity>
    <activity
        theme='@res/0x01030007'
        name='com.hyprmx.android.sdk.activity.HyprMXRequiredInformationActivity'
        configChanges='0x00000DA0'>
    </activity>
    <activity
        theme='@res/0x01030007'
        name='com.hyprmx.android.sdk.activity.HyprMXNoOffersActivity'
        configChanges='0x00000DA0'>
    </activity>
    <activity
        theme='@res/0x01030007'
        name='com.hyprmx.android.sdk.videoplayer.HyprMXVideoPlayerActivity'
        configChanges='0x00000DA0'
        hardwareAccelerated='true'>
    </activity>
    <activity
        name='com.ironsource.adapters.hyprmx.MediationHMXActivity'
        configChanges='0x40000FB4'>
    </activity>
    <receiver
        name='com.halfbrick.mortar.StoreIntentReceiver'
        exported='true'>
      <intent-filter>
        <action
            name='com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER'>
        </action>
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver
        name='com.halfbrick.mortar.LocalNotificationReceiver'
        process=':remote'>
    </receiver>
    <service
        name='com.halfbrick.mortar.FirebaseMessagingService'>
      <intent-filter>
        <action
            name='com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT'>
        </action>
      </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <activity
        name='com.halfbrick.mortar.MortarGameLauncherActivity'>
      <intent-filter>
        <action
            name='android.intent.action.MAIN'>
        </action>
        <category
            name='android.intent.category.LAUNCHER'>
        </category>
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        name='com.halfbrick.mortar.UserDataConsentActivity'
        launchMode='2'
        screenOrientation='6'>
    </activity>
    <activity
        theme='@res/0x01030010'
        name='com.android.billingclient.api.ProxyBillingActivity'
        configChanges='0x000005B0'>
    </activity>
    <service
        name='com.google.firebase.components.ComponentDiscoveryService'
        exported='false'>
      <meta-data
          name='com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.analytics.connector.internal.AnalyticsConnectorRegistrar'
          value='com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar'>
      </meta-data>
      <meta-data
          name='com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthRegistrar'
          value='com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar'>
      </meta-data>
      <meta-data
          name='com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.firestore.FirestoreRegistrar'
          value='com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar'>
      </meta-data>
      <meta-data
          name='com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.functions.FunctionsRegistrar'
          value='com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar'>
      </meta-data>
      <meta-data
          name='com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.iid.Registrar'
          value='com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar'>
      </meta-data>
    </service>
    <activity
        theme='@res/0x01030010'
        name='com.google.firebase.auth.internal.FederatedSignInActivity'
        permission='com.google.firebase.auth.api.gms.permission.LAUNCH_FEDERATED_SIGN_IN'
        exported='true'
        excludeFromRecents='true'
        launchMode='2'>
    </activity>
    <service
        name='com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService'
        exported='true'>
      <intent-filter
          priority='-500'>
        <action
            name='com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT'>
        </action>
      </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <receiver
        name='com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver'
        permission='com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND'
        exported='true'>
      <intent-filter>
        <action
            name='com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE'>
        </action>
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <service
        name='com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService'
        exported='true'>
      <intent-filter
          priority='-500'>
        <action
            name='com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT'>
        </action>
      </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <provider
        name='com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider'
        exported='false'
        authorities='com.halfbrick.jetpackjoyride.firebaseinitprovider'
        initOrder='100'>
    </provider>
    <provider
        name='com.crashlytics.android.CrashlyticsInitProvider'
        exported='false'
        authorities='com.halfbrick.jetpackjoyride.crashlyticsinitprovider'
        initOrder='90'>
    </provider>
    <provider
        name='com.helpshift.support.providers.HelpshiftFileProvider'
        exported='false'
        authorities='com.halfbrick.jetpackjoyride.helpshift.fileprovider'
        grantUriPermissions='true'>
      <meta-data
          name='android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS'
          resource='@res/0x7F080002'>
      </meta-data>
    </provider>
    <activity
        theme='@res/0x7F0D000E'
        name='com.helpshift.support.activities.ParentActivity'>
    </activity>
    <activity
        theme='@res/0x7F0D0108'
        name='com.helpshift.support.HSReview'
        configChanges='0x00000480'>
    </activity>
    <activity
        theme='@res/0x7F0D000E'
        name='com.helpshift.campaigns.activities.ParentActivity'>
    </activity>
    <activity
        theme='@res/0x01030010'
        name='com.helpshift.campaigns.activities.NotificationActivity'
        taskAffinity=''
        excludeFromRecents='true'
        launchMode='2'
        configChanges='0x00002484'
        noHistory='true'>
    </activity>
    <service
        name='com.helpshift.campaigns.services.NotificationService'
        exported='false'>
    </service>
    <activity
        theme='@res/0x7F0D021B'
        name='com.facebook.FacebookActivity'
        configChanges='0x000005B0'>
    </activity>
    <activity
        name='com.facebook.CustomTabMainActivity'>
    </activity>
    <activity
        name='com.facebook.CustomTabActivity'>
    </activity>
    <provider
        name='com.facebook.marketing.internal.MarketingInitProvider'
        exported='false'
        authorities='com.halfbrick.jetpackjoyride.MarketingInitProvider'>
    </provider>
    <provider
        name='com.facebook.internal.FacebookInitProvider'
        exported='false'
        authorities='com.halfbrick.jetpackjoyride.FacebookInitProvider'>
    </provider>
    <receiver
        name='com.facebook.CurrentAccessTokenExpirationBroadcastReceiver'
        exported='false'>
      <intent-filter>
        <action
            name='com.facebook.sdk.ACTION_CURRENT_ACCESS_TOKEN_CHANGED'>
        </action>
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
  </application>
</manifest>
```

As advised by Firelord, the following command was executed.

```
adb logcat -v long > backup_log.txt
```

and something strange appear as follows:

```
[ E/BackupRestoreConfirmation ]
Unable to communicate with mount service: no permission to access the crypt keeper: Neither user 10004 nor current process has android.permission.STORAGE_INTERNAL.
```

Comment: `ALLOW_BACKUP:NO` in the manifest of the app. Developers can lock their apps against being backed-up, unfortunately. I usually mention that along the 41 byte files – as that's the most likely cause for them.

Comment: @Izzy, I include the manifest of the app to the question. I could not find the ALLOW_BACKUP. Is there other file that I can search to get this value?

Comment: Hmm, according to the [Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element#allowbackup), if it's not specified, then "allow backup" is true by default though. However, now that we know the game, perhaps [How can I backup Jetpack Joyride save games on Android?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/130501) might be related?

Comment: @AndrewT. The Helium Backup could not backup on the mentioned phone and I don't want to create HalfBrick Profile. I just want to backup and play offline.

Comment: Strange, but I agree with @AndrewT. here: AFAIK it defaults to TRUE if not set. So no idea what goes wrong here. Logcat might give a clue.

Comment: Before running the adb backup command, can you run `adb logcat -v long > backup_log.txt` in a new tab or window, then run the backup and when it completes, cancel the logcat and provide us the output using a code-paste service? You may want to remove your email address or any personal information  from the log manually.

Comment: @Firelord, Many thanks. Question updated with adb logcat with one particular strange line.

Comment: Thanks, but we need the complete log.