# Where can I find User Data of an app?

Tags: applications, data-transfer

I have downloaded an app on my phone because I want to take out information from it. It has pages (In image form, probably PNG) that I need on my computer. I went to storage and I clicked on the app, in "Space used" it says the app size is 57.27MB, but I want is the user data (Because when I first downloaded the app, the pages weren't there, but when I opened the app they gave the option to download the pages and I clicked the option to downloaded all pages). The user data is 288MB, and the total size of the pages is probably somewhere in 200MBs. So it means the pages are in "User Data." When I connect my phone to my computer (through USB) this shows up:

[image]

So if the images are in User Data, from which of those can I locate the "User Data" of the app?
Note the app's name is *Al-Muhaffiz* and it was published by *Mahad Al-Zahra Publications.*

Comment: Look under `/sdcard/Android/data/com.aliasgarmurtaza.hifzalquran`, but all data might not be there. Private data is in `/data/data/com.aliasgarmurtaza.hifzalquran` which you can't access without rooting your phone.

Comment: Data could also be found in hidden folders starting with *.<filename>*

You can easily find a hidden folder using the built-in *File Manager* or a 3rd party application.

Once you open your directory,  tab the hamburger icon and select "show hidden folders"

Comment: @IrfanLatif is there anyway to access it without root?

Comment: May be and may be not. `adb backup` trick may work, but I never tested. See [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/182384/218526) and [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/28481/218526). Is it a Quran app? Most probably it will be placing files in first location I've given in above comment, or may be simply creating a (possibly hidden) directory in `/sdcard` if it has Storage permission granted.